# Difference between ‘,’ and ‘and’ in whereCondition of DolphinDB sql() function?

Tags: sql, dolphindb

I am wondering if there is any difference in using ',' and 'and' with SQL functions in DolphinDB, especially when there `where` clause is used?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they are not different:
'Symbols “and”, “&&” and “,” can be used to perform logical “AND” operation on multiple conditions in a where clause.'

From: https://dolphindb.com/help/SQLStatements/where.html